# Doubles as template type?

Tags: c++, templates, double

I am trying to create a generic class that handles ints, doubles, and strings.  However, when trying to instantiate the template class with  I get the following error message:

```
error: 'double' is not a valid type for a template constant parameter
```

The instantiation works completely fine with int types, as does the internal code, though I haven't made it to string types yet.  It seems as if this should be fine, since you can instantiate vector, etc.  Is there something I am missing here?

```
// file forest.h

template<typename NODETYPE> class Forest
{
    template<NODETYPE>                                              // Line 15
    friend Forest<NODETYPE>& operator+(Forest<NODETYPE>& f1,
                                       Forest<NODETYPE>& f2);

    template<NODETYPE>                                              // Line 17
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& output,
                               const Forest<NODETYPE>& f1);

    template<NODETYPE>                                              // Line 19
    friend void outputHelper(ostream& output,
                             const ForestNode<NODETYPE>& currentNode,
                             int depth);
    /* ... */
};
```

The error occurs as follows:

```
\project 4\forest.h|341|instantiated from here|
\project 4\forest.h|15|error: 'double' is not a valid type for a template constant parameter|
\project 4\forest.h|17|error: 'double' is not a valid type for a template constant parameter|
\project 4\forest.h|19|error: 'double' is not a valid type for a template constant parameter|
```

Comment: @joedillian: "Is there something I am missing here?" - Yes. You're missing some code in your question. It will be extremely helpful if you can show us a minimal code snippet that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Are you trying to have a template type parameter, have template constant parameter, or do template specializations?  They're different things.  Maybe you meant to do one of them, and did another on accident?  Please show some code, and we'll help you figure out which you were doing, and which you should be doing.

Comment: To be honest, I'm not really sure how to make a microcosm of said error.  Last time I posted, I got told i would recieve no help because my code sample was too large.  And now I'm told I'm going to be ignored because I can't provide code. :-/  I will post the entirety of my code momentarily.

Comment: @joedillian: The reason why we ask for a *minimal* code snippet is because it forces you to actually look at the problem. I'm not saying that you didn't put any effort into your question, but actually trying to reproduce the problem with a minimal code snippet will help you understand its root cause. Also, it allows us to pinpoint the root cause better and faster and allow for more relevant answers.

Comment: @joe: If you understand your code, you should be able to strip out the irrelevant parts and post what's left. Asking a question about errors in your code without code is like walking to a car repair shop without your car and asking "what's wrong with my car?".

Comment: @GMan I guess I don't quite understand my code then, TBH.  This is the first assignment I've ever been given where I am to use templates, friend functions, and operator-overloading.

Comment: @joedillian: A huge majority of the code wasn't relevant to the question. I edited out only the irrelevant parts, based on the line numbers provided in the compiler error message. (Although looking at the rest, I still see some problems, but those are best suited for another question.) This is how you post minimal code snippets - post only the code that caused the error.

Comment: I see.  But i thought the idea was to give something that could be compiled, and reproduce the error.  Sorry if I've sounded confrontational, I'm just really frustrated with this project at the moment.  I'll try to keep the style of your edit in mind when I have questions in the future.

Comment: @joedillian: Don't worry about it - it's good to have compilable code, but at the same time you don't want to paste in 10,000 characters of code. In this case, I used the line numbers in the compiler error message to trim out irrelevant parts. By trimming out what's unimportant, we can answer your questions faster.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
template<NODETYPE> friend Forest<NODETYPE>& operator+(Forest<NODETYPE>& f1, Forest<NODETYPE>& f2);

    template<NODETYPE> friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& output, const Forest<NODETYPE>& f1);

    template<NODETYPE> friend void outputHelper(ostream& output, const ForestNode<NODETYPE>& currentNode, int depth);
```

These friend declarations are invalid. If you have a templated class, you don't need to repeat it's template arguments when referring to it within it's own scope. Even if you intended to allow any other instantiation of Forest, then you would have to use typename or class and call NODETYPE something else.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I kind of understand what my mistake was.  Basically I was using NODETYPE to refer both to the type of the forest, and the type of the input in the friend function, right?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `double` (or `float` or `long double`) as a template parameter with any compiler that's even sort of close to conforming. What you *can't* do is use a floating point value as a **non-type** template parameter.

The closest you can get to this is generally passing the floating point value(s) to the ctor, and store it/them in your object.

Answer (score 2):

you're most likely trying to do something like this:

```
template_type<3.1415926d> blarg;
```

somewhere, somehow.
this is not allowed. doubles (floats, long doubles) are not allowed as template constant parameters.
now something you probably will run into too is this:

```
template_type<"life, the universe and everything"> blarg;
```

this too is (for some reason) not admissable, since the pointer type should have external linkage so:

```
char* my_str="life, the universe and everything";
template_type<my_str> blarg;
```

shoule be just fine

now as a side note: some compilers do or did allow floating-point constants (iirc gcc 3, probably others)

Answer (score 1):

Template constant parameter of floating point value (like double) are forbidden.

```
template <double x> struct A {};
```

However you can instantiate a template with type `double` (what you'd like to do, if I get your question).

```
template <typename T> struct A {};
... 
A<double> a;
```

If you want to specialize your template for the specific type double, then do

```
template <typename T> struct A {};
template <> struct A<double> {...};
```

Comment: My class is declared with template<typename T> and the friend functions functions are declared as template<T>.  Yet when I try to instantiate class<double>* foo = new class<double>() it says that double is not an acceptable parameter.

Comment: Ok I see. The error msg may be misleading but you can't do `template<NODETYPE> friend Forest<NODETYPE>& operator+(Forest<NODETYPE>& f1, Forest<NODETYPE>& f2);` that is something like `template <T> fun(T t);` A correct prototype looks like `template <typename T> fun(T t);`